MPFR 4.2.1 in Solaris 10 x86_64 gmp.h and libgmp seem to have different versions
I am trying to compile the latest version of GCC to try compiling Modula 3 CM3 but I first have to have versions of GMP, MPFR, and MPC.

GMP installs correctly using
./configure --build-x86_64-oracle-solaris10 --enable-cxx
make
make check
make install


But when I run ./configure from MPFR it fails on
checking if we can link with GMP... no

and gives me an error
configure: error: libgmp not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared)


but when I run
./configure --with-gmp-build=/usr/gmp-6.3.0

(the directory where I made gmp) it first gets past linking with GMP then
checking if gmp.h and libgmp version are the same... (6.3.0/6.1.2) no

and gives me a warning stating they seem to be different versions, but still finishes with the configure. But it fails the make check after make works.

I don't know what to do, I can't get any newer version of gcc than gcc5g++ from opencsw that I don't have to do myself.
I also have a similar problem when trying to ./configure MPC. I can give the full terminal outputs when I go through the process of doing GMP and both versions of MPFR if needed. I also only use the root user.
Here is my env
Script started on Wed Dec 18 20:20:05 2024
# env
AB_CARDCATALOG=/usr/dt/share/answerbooks/C/ab_cardcatalog
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID=
DISPLAY=:0.0
DTAPPSEARCHPATH=//.dt/appmanager:/usr/dt/appconfig/appmanager/%L:/usr/dt/appconfig/appmanager/C
DTDATABASESEARCHPATH=//.dt/types,/usr/dt/appconfig/types/%L,/usr/dt/appconfig/types/C
DTDEVROOT=
DTHELPSEARCHPATH=//.dt/help/root-dhcp-137-112-128-55-0/%H://.dt/help/root-dhcp-137-112-128-55-0/%H.sdl://.dt/help/root-dhcp-137-112-128-55-0/%H.hv://.dt/help/%H://.dt/help/%H.sdl://.dt/help/%H.hv:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/%L/%H:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/%L/%H.sdl:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/%L/%H.hv:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/C/%H:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/C/%H.sdl:/usr/dt/appconfig/help/C/%H.hv
DTSCREENSAVERLIST=StartDtscreenSwarm StartDtscreenQix     StartDtscreenFlame StartDtscreenHop StartDtscreenImage StartDtscreenLife     StartDtscreenRotor StartDtscreenPyro StartDtscreenWorm StartDtscreenBlank
DTSOURCEPROFILE=true
DTUSERSESSION=root-dhcp-137-112-128-55-0
DTXSERVERLOCATION=local
EDITOR=/usr/dt/bin/dtpad
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=Default
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/var/tmp/keyring-N3i32r/socket
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc://.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=yes
G_FILENAME_ENCODING=@locale,UTF-8
HELPPATH=/usr/openwin/lib/locale:/usr/openwin/lib/help
HOME=/
LANG=C
LOGNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
MANPATH=/usr/dt/man:/usr/man:/usr/openwin/share/man
OPENWINHOME=/usr/openwin
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/ucb:/opt/csw/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/opt/csw/gnu:/opt/csw/bdb48:/opt/csw/share/java/ant/bin:/usr/local/bin
PWD=/
SDT_NO_DTDBCACHE=1
SDT_NO_TOOLTALK=1
SESSIONTYPE=altDt
SESSION_MANAGER=local/dhcp-137-112-128-55:/tmp/.ICE-unix/28123,inet6/dhcp-137-112-128-55:35258,inet/dhcp-137-112-128-55:35259
SESSION_SVR=dhcp-137-112-128-55
SHELL=/sbin/sh
START_SPECKEYSD=no
TERM=xterm
TZ=US/East-Indiana
USER=root
WINDOWID=41943088
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/openwin/lib/locale/%L/%T/%N%S:/usr/openwin/lib/%T/%N%S
XMBINDDIR=/usr/dt/lib/bindings
XMICONBMSEARCHPATH=//.dt/icons/%B%M.bm://.dt/icons/%B%M.pm://.dt/icons/%B:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B%M.bm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B%M.pm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B%M.bm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B%M.pm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B
XMICONSEARCHPATH=//.dt/icons/%B%M.pm://.dt/icons/%B%M.bm://.dt/icons/%B:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B%M.pm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B%M.bm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/%L/%B:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B%M.pm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B%M.bm:/usr/dt/appconfig/icons/C/%B
_=/usr/bin/gnome-session
dtstart_sessionlogfile=/dev/null
# exci  it

script done on Wed Dec 18 20:20:17 2024

